# Programmatically Send webpage as email via VBA

Tags: html, vba, outlook

I have a webpage I formatted in HTML. Says it is the following:

```
<html>
<b> test </b>
```

I want to know how to send an email such that the email contents are **`test`**
 (this text is bolded if your computer cannot load it), and not `<b> test </b>`.

Comment: If the recipient is receiving `<b> test </b>` then I would guess you are setting `MailItem.Body` to this string. Try `MailItem.HtmlBody = <html>
<b> test </b></html>`

Comment: @TonyDallimore Thanks! If you want to post that comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the right one. If not, I'll just answer it myself tomorrow.

Comment: I see you have already posted this as an answer.  I suggest you accept your answer.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Stack Overflow won't let me until tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to change in the code where you put `.body`. This needs to be changed to `.HTMLBody`. This will allow the email to be parsed as html. Thanks @Tony Dallimore for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Gmail: 
click "compose" then click the arrow-type-thingy next to the trashcan in the bottom-right and click "plain text mode"
These apply to 99% of the email-companies but they vary depending on company

Comment: the opposite to plain text mode is rich text wich is used to make nicer, formatted looking emails

Comment: Hi, I tagged this as outlook VBA because I need to do it in outlook. That way I can automate about 100 emails with different names. Any ideas?

Comment: Press new, then the arrow next to the capital A in the bottom menu and press "Send as an unformatted text"